# AWS Error: Condition parameter type does not match schema type (Service: DynamoDb, Status Code: 400)

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I get the below error when logging into my dev angular system, I'm using AWS Serverless, Amplify Cognito and Graphql.

```
One or more parameter values were invalid:  
Condition parameter type does not match schema type
(Service: DynamoDb, Status Code: 400, 
Request ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, 
Extended Request ID: null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have solved this already but for me this was occurring because in the condition I was comparing a number to a column that was of type string.

```
"expression": "sortId > 0",
```

Using the above as an example sortId is of type String but 0 is of course a number.